# how to add exposed drop-down filter with options in a view of custom table

Tags: 7, views

In a drupal 7 website, I have a view that is based on a custom table. I have a **status** column in that custom table, which is type of integer and has 0 or 1 value, and in a view I want to add exposed filter with dropdown, with values somehow like below

```
$options[0] = 'No';
$options[1] = 'Yes';
```

So that a user can choose a value from dropdown and filter out data.

So in my views.inc file I have implemented hook_views_data(), then I have added the following code to make that field accessible in a view

```
$data['custom_users']['status'] = array(
      'title' => t('User Status'),
      'help' => t('User Status'),
      'field' => array(
        'click sortable' => TRUE,
      ), 
      'filter' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_numeric',
      ), 
      'sort' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
      ),
  );
```

Now when I am trying to add exposed filter using this field I am not able to make it available as dropdown. I am only getting a textfield as exposed filter for this field.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked this article? https://atendesigngroup.com/articles/drupal-7-views-drop-down-exposed-filter-text-field

Comment: @PatrickScheffer Hello. Thanks for your response. Yes I have checked that article, and method mentioned in it somehow works with actual field table, in my case I have only one custom table that stores form submissions, some simple values like name and other details. So there I have a status column that holds either 0 or 1 value. In views I was expecting to have drop down option, like in case of node you can have filter with Published & Unpublished options in dropdown.

Comment: How does your views_handler_filter_numeric class look?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hook_form_alter()` for this.
simply change the field type to select and add your options.
here is my working code

```
// implements hook_form_alter
function project_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id === 'views_exposed_form') {
    $view = $form_state['view'];
    // add your view name in 'view_name'.
    if ($view->name === 'view_name') { 
      // Checking status field is exists or not.
      if (isset($form['status'])) {
        $form['status']['#type'] = 'select';
        $form['status']['#empty_value'] = '';
        $form['status']['#empty_option'] = 'All';
        $form['status']['#options'] = array('0' => 'No', '1' => 'Yes');
        $form['status']['#size'] = 1;
        $form['status']['#attributes'] = array('id' => 'status-list');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

hope this will work :).